# The rendered images differ from the images in the toggle camera view

Tags: rendering, camera, orthographic

I am using an orthographic camera. Why do the rendered images differ from the toggle camera view? Please refer to the attachment. My images appear distorted. How can I make my rendered images the same as the toggle camera view? Thanks in advance.
Chen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to different lighting. Currently the viewport shows objects in studio lights but the rendering happens in sunlight. To see the rendered image in viewport: Change *Viewport Shading* to *Rendered*:

[image]